# Discovering operating power of a component without destroying it and without specification

Tags: voltage, testing

I have a laser pointer component that I figured was a 9V pointer, and it worked nicely and shone very bright. I kept decreasing the voltage to see how low it could go, and it turns out it runs great on 3v!

I tried 12v also and it worked very well. How high can I go?

[image: Laser component and power cell only]

Comment: Keep increasing the voltage until the light stops coming out.  The answer is then a little lower than that point.

Comment: ... because it breaks at that point right?

Comment: Bounds testing is destructive 99.9% of the time.

Comment: How about opening it up and looking inside?  There is most likely a power control circuit internal to the laser diode... (Lots of laser diodes have monitor photo diodes built in.)   a bare diode would blow up with 9V across it.

Comment: ...but maybe not with an alkaline 9V battery, which has a very high internal resistance.

Comment: @PhilFrost, What is the internal resistance of a 9V?  Looking at the laser I'm guessing ~100 mA will fry it.   I tested a new 9V.  (open - 9.62V, 1 kohm - 9.47V, 100 - 8.94, 10 - 6.23V)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold [BU-902: How to Measure Internal Resistance](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_measure_internal_resistance)

Answer (score 3):

A common failure mode for semiconductors is overheating. You could remove the case to gain access to the internal components, then somehow monitor the temperature of the device (IR camera, thermocouple, etc). Arbitrarily decide what an allowable maximum junction temperature could be (look at datasheets for similar devices), then increase power to the device until you get near this temperature.

A more crude version of this: put your finger on it and turn up the power until it's hot.

Of course this only means maybe you won't destroy the device. There are other failure modes, and you can't account for them all. It's possible your arbitrarily selected maximum junction temperature is too high and it overheats anyway. If it's really important, you need a datasheet. No way around it.

Comment: Thank you, this is an awesome answer. It has changed my disposition about the issue from hopelessly awaiting its unpredictable failure to understanding the most probable mitigating factor about the failure I'm trying to avoid, and knowing what I can do and look for to find what I am looking for while preventing failure. Right on. +1 Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Quite often there are identifying numbers which will let you find out the specification, or you can guess based on similar products. I suspect that's a standard red laser diode limited to 5mW by law, and that it requires about 2V. It may have an internal series resistor which is saving it from self-destructing.

(Vast supply of information: http://www.repairfaq.org/sam/laserdps.htm)